# On PostBuildEvent - $(TargetDir) is different when build in Azure DevOps VSTS than local machine

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, post-build-event

I have a solution named MySolution with a project called MySolution.MyProject.

If I set a post-build event using $(TargetDir) in MySolution.MyProject, the variable points to c:\source\MySolution\MySolution.MyProject\bin.

When building on VSTS, that same variable refers to d:\a\1\s\MySolution\bin\

Notice how the one on VSTS is missing the project subfolder.

Please see del command in the first line of the screenshot. Del command is trying to delete file in MySolution\bin\Release\File.exe although it is copied to D:\a\1\s\bin\Release\File.exe

[image]

Comment: Would you be comfortable adding screenshots? I've never seen this occur.

Comment: added screen shot in the original question

Comment: @Krrish How did you set a post-build event? I took a simple test in one project of my solution: `echo Output written to $(TargetDir)`, and got correct output. Locally, the output is "Output written to D:\Workspace\VSTS\TestCase\TestCaseProject-branch\TestCaseProject\bin\Debug\". And DevOps pipeline output is "Output written to d:\a\48\s\TestCaseProject\bin\Debug\".